# Error in SOQL query on Custom Setting

Tags: apex

I have a hierarchical custom setting from where I want to query the Profile Name and some fields from that setting. Is there any way I can profile name/user name from the custom setting... I've tried below query to return fields from the setting...

```
 SELECT TYPEOF SetupOwner
    WHEN Profile THEN Id, Name END
    Discount__c, Price__c
    FROM Hierarchy_Object__c
    WHERE SetupOwnerId IN (Select Id FROM Profile)
```

It is throwing an error says "SOQL TYPEOF expressions cannot have an alias"... Can anyone help me how to resolve the query.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing comma in the SOQL after `END`.

To include `fieldList` in the SOQL query with `TYPEOF`, you can either include the fields list after `END` :

```
 SELECT 
    TYPEOF SetupOwner
       WHEN Profile THEN Id, Name 
    END,
    Discount__c, Price__c
    FROM Hierarchy_Object__c
    WHERE SetupOwnerId IN (Select Id FROM Profile)
```

Or add them at the beginning :

```
 SELECT  Discount__c, Price__c,
    TYPEOF SetupOwner
      WHEN Profile THEN Id, Name 
    END
    FROM Hierarchy_Object__c
    WHERE SetupOwnerId IN (Select Id FROM Profile)
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) for the TYPEOF syntax

Comment: I have added the VF page as answer. Can you check and let me know what I missed....

Comment: @SaiVineeth This is a different topic, please post it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

It worked and didn't throw any error. I wanted to display Profile Name and the fields in a vf page. So I added the query results to a List. But the list returning no values...Here is my VF page...

````
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Profiles">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objList}" var="li">
                    <apex:column value="{!li.Name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!li.Discount__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Get Profiles" action="{!settingsClass}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>```
````

Comment: This is an additional question and it is not appropriate to post as an answer. could you please post a new question for this, as this is different from your initial question